# I want to record some user actions for my python flask app deployed on heroku. Suggest me ways to do it

Tags: python-3.x, api, flask, heroku

I have a Python Flask app deployed on heroku. I want to record user interactions in a file(kind of log file). Since heroku storage is temporary, even though I append actions to a log file the data is lost. I don't want use a DataBase for this simple task. My idea is to have an API that can modify files in a remote file system. I am looking for such remote file system(cloud storage) along with API to accomplish my task.

For example, let us assume that I have 3 buttons on my app and a `tracking.txt` file. Then

if `button1` is clicked, I want to write(append) `1` to `tracking.txt` .

Similarly for `button2` and `button3`.

I have searched the internet but didn't find any that can fit my exact need or I didn't understand any of them well.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

PS: I am open to change my thought if there's no way other than using DB.

Comment: What's the point in implementing a hacky solution when the end result is much more messier? Why don't program it right from the beginning? Furthermore there are plenty of such services and you said you have found them but did not understand them. How can we help then? Just pick one, get into it, show code where you are stuck. Are you willing to pay for such services because most of them are premium/have a free trial. Usually you only really need these services when your website is ultra complex and you do some heavy data analysis. What's your exact purpose in tracking?

Comment: I want to track few clicks on my app(out of very few I want to record which one is clicked. As simple as writing "button1 clicked" to a text file). I just need a place to store/update the data using API calls or similar kind. I don't need any complex data analysis service and I can't afford to pay for any service. I actually searched the internet but couldn't find an exact one that can fit my need. I request you to share any if you know.

Comment: https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack - https://www.blastanalytics.com/google-analytics-360-standard-comparison --- or DIY: https://github.com/greenstick/interactor - https://greenstick.github.io/interactor/ just pipe the information into a database.

Comment: I will check them. Thanks! BTW I updated my question for clear understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

one possible solution is to use Amazon S3 together with the Boto3, the Amazon Web Services (AWS) SDK for Python.

You can copy (push) your file from Heroku to an S3 bucket (at intervals or after every change, this depends on your logic)

```
import boto3

session = boto3.session.Session()

s3 = session.client(
        service_name='s3',
        aws_access_key_id='MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
        aws_secret_access_key='MY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
    )

# upload file from local path to S3 Bucker
s3.upload_file(Bucket='data', Key='files/file1.log', Filename='/tmp/file1.log')
```

One option with this approach is that you can use [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) for your local development, hence only your (production-like) application on Heroku will send files to S3, while during development you can work offline